# Gitlab code quality E0401: unable to import

Tags: python, gitlab, gitlab-ci, software-quality, code-climate

I am using gitlab [code quality](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/code_quality.html) with `Code-Quality.gitlab-ci.yml` in my configuration (it relies on Code Climate), and I have import errors on the code quality report as shown below:

[image]

I also have the libraries (`pandas` here) in `requirements.txt` at the root of my repo.

Why do I have these false positive errors, and how could I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Several months ago, I noticed that the code climate reports feature have some flaws.

1. The declared report file **has to be there**, even if no issues were detected in your project.
2. And as the report is supposed to be JSON, the **content of an empty report has to be `[]`**

I guess you're facing the same issue